# Matching letters in 2 strings with haskell

Tags: string, haskell, match, letters

I just started with haskell and im wondering if there is a easy way to match the letters between 2 string and output them.

like:

iced and liked will return i,e,d

Thank you!

Comment: Please specify more carefully what you mean with "match". Does the order of the letters count? What if there are multiples? From the information you've provided so far, this can be anything from a simple set intersection to a [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence) problem.

Comment: I mean the matching letter within the strings just like the example i gave.
If you put in bold and cold the return string will be o,l,d because both strings use those 3 letters

Comment: What about `dloc` and `bold`? Or `boooold` and `coold`?

Comment: @Sevo You're happy with the answer, but please could you answer hammar's questions, and edit your question with that information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Data.Set.intersection`:

```
 import qualified Data.Set as S

 sharedLetters str1 str2 = S.toList $ S.intersection (S.fromList str1) (S.fromList str2)
```

EDIT: As @jozefg pointed out, there is a function in `Data.List` which does the same for lists:

```
 > import Data.List (intersect)
 > intersect "liked" "iced"
 "ied"
```

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning the list equivalent since the oP is new to Haskell and probably doesn't knwo about sets

Comment: haha im trying to let it work, only got error outputting this:
import Data.List (intersect)

main = do
 putStrLn "Woord1:"; a <- readLn
 putStrLn "Woord2:"; b <- readLn
 
 putStrLn intersect((read a) (read b))

Comment: hmm maybe hard to read the code like that way?

Comment: @Sevo: Try [something like this](http://hpaste.org/88351).